# How do you set the timeout for macros with xlwings?

Tags: python, excel, applescript, xlwings

I have macros that can take up to 2 minutes but i keep hitting the OS automation timeout and it doesn't appear that setting the timeout via 'properties' method is having any effect.  Anyone know if this is the correct way to manage this?

```
app = xlwings.App(visible=True, add_book=False)
with app.properties(timeout=6000) as app2:
    book = app2.books.open(location)
    sheet = book.sheets("Sheet Name")

    print("timeout ->", app2.timeout)  # prints 6000 
    
    m = book.macro('Solver_Name')
    m()
```

Error:
Command Failed:
OSERROR: -1712
MESSAGE: Apple event timed out.
COMMAND: app('/Application/Microsoft Excel.app', newinstance=(0, 18448791)).run_VB_macro("'filename.xlsm'!Solver_Name")

Tried setting timeout via properties method.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with integrating applescript and vba but the `with timeout` statement isn't a property of any application, rather, it is an applescript statement. Typically, you would use it by telling a command (or block thereof) to use a longer timeout duration. For example, `tell app "excel" ; open workbook x ; with timeout 300 ; format range y ; end timeout;`. If excel vba offers a timeout property —as in your script— then that is a different beast and the applescript timeout default of 120 seconds endures.